# Custom button with an icon in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to create custom button with an icon in Google Spreadsheets? I know I can create custom menu items, but button is more user-friendly.

[image: see where I want to add a button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a menu item where you are point out to, but you can add custom [Drawings](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_extensions#drawings) and [Images](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_extensions#images) that can trigger a script function. This may even be better as you can position these buttons closer to the data/point of action.